# How to send a double type to another computer through the same LAN?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, lan, data-transfer

I've created a calculator which outputs two double numbers based on given numbers, using c# windows form application.

I would like to output these numbers **onto another computer** that is connected to the LAN (Ethernet). I've tried to use both sockets and WCF yet couldn't find a proper way to make it work.

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(DnsGetHostName());
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 61);

Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

try
{
    sender.Connect(remoteEP);

    lblInfo.Text = sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();

    byte[] azm = new byte[] {byte.Parse(Azm.ToString()) };
    byte[] ele = new byte[] {byte.Parse(Ele.ToString()) };

   sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
   sender. Close();
}
```

this is something I tried to make yet it didn't work.

I hope what I have requested is possible and really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? What happens when you run your program? How does this differ from what you want?

Comment: See the marked duplicate for information on converting `double` values to a `byte[]`. It's actually a bit more thorough than you need, as it shows how to deal with more than one `double` at a time. Feel free to ignore the `double` array handling and just use the part that converts each `double` value. Note that once you have a `byte[]`, sending the data is just a matter of transmitting bytes, a very basic and fundamental operation for the network API. You shouldn't need help with that, but if you do, post a new question and be sure to include a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Note that your current "conversion" code is completely wrong. Assuming `Azm` and `Ele` are `double` variables, then at best what you've done is to cast from `double` to `byte` the hard way. At worst, you've got code that will throw an exception most of the time, because typically the text representation of a `double` value cannot be parsed as a `byte` value. The one answer posted below compounds your mistake by carrying on in the same vein rather than providing good, useful numeric conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to actually send the data.

```
byte[] azm = new byte[] {byte.Parse(Azm.ToString()) };
byte[] ele = new byte[] {byte.Parse(Ele.ToString()) };

sender.Send(azm); //<-- You forgot to call these two.
sender.Send(ele); //<-- You forgot to call these two.

sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
sender. Close();
```

Read more about `Socket.Send()` on the [**MSDN documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w93yy28a(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Keep in mind though that a `byte` can only go from 0 to 255. So if you plan to use larger numbers you have to use an `int` or `long` instead. This also means that the endpoint have to read more bytes.

```
byte[] azm = BitConverter.GetBytes(int.Parse(Azm.ToString()));
byte[] ele = BitConverter.GetBytes(int.Parse(Ele.ToString()));
```

If you use an `int` the endpoint has to read 4 bytes, if you use `long` the endpoint has to read 8 bytes.

Reversing [**`BitConverter.GetBytes()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4(v=vs.110).aspx) can be done like this:

```
int azm = BitConverter.ToInt32(<byte array here>, 0);
...or...
long azm = BitConverter.ToInt64(<byte array here>, 0);
```